# Slow mysql query - select

Tags: php, mysql, performance, select

This query takes about 10 seconds to execute the first time, and then each consecutive time it takes upwards of a minute:

```
SELECT qQuoteDateTime, 
       qLastSalePrice, 
       qNetChangePrice, 
       qNetChangePct,
       qShareVolumeQty 
  FROM quotes 
  WHERE qSymbol='GE'
```

The table I'm using has about 2300 records.  I've seen someone implement a decently fast query to display all of the records, but I don't have access to the code he used.

How can I speed this up?

Comment: What data-types are all of your columns? Can you please post the DDL as both Your Common Sense and reko_t are correct. If all your columns are nchar or a blob etc then this might make more sense.

Comment: What is the "size" of the data? Few KBs, a couple of MBs ore more? I once had similar problem with MySQL data; I had a few hundred rows but the size of the table was ~1.5GB; traversing that much amount of data can take a few seconds.

Answer (score 4):

Run an [EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/explain.html) on the query to see why it's slow. The most likely cause is that `qSymbol` column is missing an index. Create an index on the column if it's missing one and you should see a considerable boost in performance, as MySQL won't have to scan through each row in the table, but can just look up the corresponding rows from the index.

Comment: For the 2300 rows it cannot be 10 sec up to minute without an index. This is just an automated answer with general info, not helping anyone but only to get rep points

Comment: It was not an automated answer at all. If you look at my history, I don't even post that much on SO, and when I do I try to genuinely help people. I also thought that 10 seconds sounds rather high for the amount of rows, but it's possible that he typoed the number, or that he's machine is simply under that much load so MySQL is choking. Or maybe it's doing a filesort on the HDD and his harddrive is on the verge of breaking. There are various reasons why it might be slow, but I don't like guessing. I could've mentioned those possible issues in my answer though, you're right about that.

Comment: @raheelshan: it makes no sense at all to use `HAVING` instead of `WHERE` in this case.

Comment: @reko_t posted the best response to this issue. Slow query? => Run EXPLAIN and add index. If that doesn't help Brian, let's try to find out other solutions.

Answer (score 3):

There is something wrong with your database. Or you are barking the wrong tree.
The query you posted here should be blazing fast for the given row count.

First of all make sure its a query, not anything else causing it.
Did you try to run this query from the console? PHPMyAdmin? Are the results the same? 
Do you run it inside of the loop by chance?
Is the row count really 2300, not 2300 thousands?